# Cannot make text italic in TextEdit (but bold and underline work fine)

Tags: macos, font, textedit

I've never seen this strange thing before. I am working on a new TextEdit file (not yet saved anywhere, but saved automatically on iCloud I assume).

The document is not plain text, therefore I believe it is RTF by default.

I used the shortcut for italic on a selection of text, and heard a "duh" sound that signifies a mistake / impossible operation.

Indeed, in the Font menu, the Italic option is greyed out - all other options aren't.

Has anyone ever seen this and knows what may cause this strange bug?

[image]

Comment: Well this is odd. Does the font you're using have a Italic "weight"? You can check that from Font Book, or try a different font. Also have to seen if Italic option works in Safe mode?

Comment: @user14492 Yeah, that's the first thing to check: does the font not have italics?

Comment: Well the font is Arial. The typeface menu lists "bold" and "regular" but not italics. Why wouldn't Arial (shipped with the computer) have italics?

Comment: @user14492 can you make your comment an answer? It solved it. Thanks!